# How to fix slight moving of Navbar when Carousel scrolls?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a weird issue. I am building a web page that has a navbar and a carousel below it. I am observing that the navbar moves down very so slightly when the carousel scrolls. I am unable to understand why this is happenning ?
Below is the code I'm using.

The navbar and carousel are both within body.

```html
<nav id="topNavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-alt-lvl2 py-0">
  ....
</nav>

<div>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="background-color:black;height:550px;overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;">
    .......
  </div>
<div>
```

Any inputs on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You have not really provided enough code for me to be able to understand what is causing the problem. One thing, does the navbar have a margin-bottom? Does the navbar only move down the once, or does it keep moving down after every slide changes? is the navbar fixed, absolute, sticky?

Comment: CSS seems to be missing? Bootstrap? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

try this css, it should work

```
nav#topNavbar { 
  display: block; 
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 99;
}
```